# section with multiple columns

Tags: docbook, docbook-5

I would like to have a section (or alike) with multiple (2) columns and fill this with a table of contents so that the items are distributed over the columns.

As a reference in LaTeX this can be accomplished with something like:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{list}{}
\item \contentsline{section}{\mbox{\hyperlink{index_item1}{First Item}}}{\ref{index_item1}}{}
\item \contentsline{section}{\mbox{\hyperlink{item2_item2}{Second Item}}}{\ref{item2_item2}}{}
\item \contentsline{section}{\mbox{\hyperlink{item2_item3}{Third Item}}}{\ref{item2_item3}}{}
\end{list}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: DocBook markup itself is not concerned with presentation aspects such as the number of columns in the rendered output. I think what you want is possible, but how to do it depends on the output formats and the toolchain(s) that you use to produce the output. Here is some information that might help if you use the DocBook XSL stylesheets to produce PDFs via XSL-FO: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/MultiColumns.html.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. The thing is that I want only for some sections to have multiple columns, so I thought there might be a command or attribute (with the section command) that gives a hint / instruction to the conversion process for multiple columns.